# SAT Geometry Problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, problem-solving

Circle O (point O is on the origin) passes through points $ A ({\sqrt 3 }, 1$) and point $B (a, 0),$ where $a$  is positive. The measure of angle AOB can be expressed as $\frac{\pi}{b}$. What is the value of $b$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The point $A$ is distance $4$ from the origin, which tells us that the radius of the circle is $2$. Therefore the point $B$ should be $2$ units from the center, so it must be $(2,0)$. Note it could have also been $(-2,0)$ but they told us $a$ is positive.

Now draw a triangle connecting $A = (\sqrt{3}, 1)$, $B = (2, 0)$ and $O = (0,0)$. Let $\theta$ be the angle $AOB$. Then we see that $\cos\theta = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and so $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that looks complicated when you first read it and then becomes simple on a second or third look.
 Many SAT questions are of this sort. Hint # 1A: remember that you have to be able to solve it in a minute if you are to finish the test, so there can't be too much depth (unlike the real world and really useful questions). Hint # 1B: On the SAT, always look for the trick.

It will take a lot longer to explain the reasoning of this question than to see the answer.

A circle with center at the origin has equation $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. This s an important fact to remember. Since we know the circle passes through A$(\sqrt3,1)$ then $(\sqrt3)^2 + 1^2 = r^2$ so $4 = r^2$ and $r = 2$. (Remember $r$ is always positive, no question of signed roots here.)

Since the circle passes through B$(a,0)$ with $a$ positive, we can simply look at the graph, or we can work out $a^2 + 0^2 = r^2$ so $a = r$ (given positive) and $a = 2$, and then we see B = $(2,0).

As is often the case with SAT questions, this one is badly worded and makes unjustified assumptions. If $b$ is any non-zero real number, then *any* angle can be expressed as $\pi / b$. However here the most likely reading would be that $b$ is intended to be an integer and probably the *minimum positive* integer. Hint #2: On the SAT assume 90 percent of the time the dumb reading (but always always look for a second option, the negative square root, the other side of the absolute value, etc.)

Now you should have followed the basic seven-word rule of geometry and trig: Draw The Diagram And Look At It. That is also Hint #3 for the SAT, Draw The Diagram And Look At It.  I would throw a quick sketch in here but have not yet learned how to insert diagrams in this format, sorry. 
So on your graph you have B $(2,0)$ and  A$(\sqrt3,1)$ on a circle center origin and radius = 2.
What angle does it look like? If your sketch is not too inaccurate you should have an idea already.
Can we prove it?

Yes. Remember the definition of $ sin(\theta)$. On a circle center origin and radius $r$, with a ray OP where P = $(x,y)$,  $sin(/theta) = y/r$ Also for completeness $cos(\theta) = x/r$ and $ tan(\theta) = y/x = $ slope of OP.
Here P = A = $(\sqrt3,1)$ so $y = \sqrt3$ and we know $r = 2$ so $ cos(\theta) = |sqrt3 / 2$. This gives us a very well-known angle which you should recognize at sight. However you could use the inverse cosine function to be sure.

We find $\theta = 30$ degrees $= \pi / 6$.

Thus we assume (minimum positive) $b = 6$

Comment: You have unnecessarily made the answer long

Comment: I was answering for a high school student who is meeting this kind of problem for the first time. As I started out saying, the problem looks complicated on first sight and only with a second or third look do you see that it is really quite simple. High school students need to get behind the scene and learn the reasoning process.
Yes this should be part of their school classes. No, very often the vital part of the subject is omitted in favour of memorizing formulas.

Comment: You took more trouble in explanation than what it needs.

Comment: Please see my reply above. If the student complains I took too much trouble helping him, then I'll cut back.

Answer (score 0):

A sketch is given below. This SAT question is not well posed, edited it as not upto the mark.

$$ a =2,\, b =6\,$$

[image: SAT Question]

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed something, the circle is completely irrelevant.  The required angle is that between $OA$ and the positive $x$-axis, which given the coordinates of $A$ is
$$\arctan\frac1{\sqrt3}=\frac\pi6\ .$$
So $b=6$.